# Communicate between two different apps in flutter (locally connected over same network)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm developing a project for my college in flutter which has a user app and service center app now I want to get them communicating with each other.
For example -: if the user orders food in a restaurant from app A. Now in app B it should show the request. From app B you can accept or decline the order and which should send an acknowledgment back to app A.

Now I know that I have to use database. For now I'm comfortable with firebase.

Now here I'm confused that if app A sends the data to firebase then how could app B will access that data/read that data and react accordingly
I have no idea how to do this.

if anyone can help me it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

To create a communication channel between two apps, you will need to have some sort of medium that can convey data from one point to another. For this purpose, Databases are used. In Flutter, you can use firebase(No SQL Database) to communicate as it is easy to learn and set-up as well. This [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) will be helpful to you to understand more about it.